# How to automatically find and add the namespace using clause of a type in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, types, namespaces, using-directives

When I try to write some function I have to add manually the required namespace.

Is there a any keyword or shortcut for auto-add the using clause like ReSharper does?

Thanks.

Comment: Does Ctrl-period not offer you options automatically?

Comment: I will try.Thanks

Comment: @Kayhan It works. Just discover that. No more headaches! It opens the refactor tooltip with several choices.  Default in french is `Ctrl+;`.